# Given path not supported error message when reading text files from folder

Tags: c#, string, error-handling, path

I have a log in page and I'm trying to get the form to read what's in the textbox + ".txt" so that it opens the corresponding page. I've managed to first check to see if it exists but then the second part doesn't work - the error message given path is not supported comes up at filePath + ".txt"

See code below:

```
public bool check_user(string pUsername)
{
    //checks first to see if user exists

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pUsername + ".txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //read first bit of data from text file eg username, data split by ";"
            string[] data = line.Split(';');
            if (data[0] == pUsername)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User found");
                return true;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("User not found, try again");

        return false;
    }

}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Read from file
    if (check_user(txtUsername.Text.Trim()))
    {

        string filePath = txtUsername + ".txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath + ".txt"))

        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //read first bit of data from text file eg username, data split by ";"
                string[] data = line.Split(';');
                if (data[0] == txtUsername.Text.Trim())
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            // read second bit of data from text file eg password, data split by ";"
            string[] user = line.Split(';');
            if (user[1] == txtPassword.Text.Trim())
            {
                // checks access levels by viewing the third part of data and corresponds to which form to open
                if (user[2] == "employee")
                {
                    EmployeeForm frm = new EmployeeForm();
                    frm.Show();

                }
                else if (user[2] == "admin")
                {
                    AdminForm frm = new AdminForm();
                    frm.Show();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login not successful, try again", "Error",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create the file name. And make sure there are no special characters in the user name.

Comment: I think there was no data in text file for second time or there was not  semicolon ( ; ) in a txt file

Comment: Are these text files in the same folder as the executable?  The way your code is currently written, that's the only way it will work.  Keep in mind that if you're running this through visual studio's debugger, the executing folder will be bin/Debug or bin/Release (depending on which configuration you're building under), so it would look for the txt files there.

Answer (score 0):

First you do this:

```
check_user(txtUsername.Text.Trim())
```

Indicating that `txtUsername` is some kind of control which has `Text` property. Two lines below you do:

```
string filePath = txtUsername + ".txt";
```

This is equivalent of

```
string filePath = txtUsername.ToString() + ".txt";
```

And because `txtUsername` is not string but some control that has `Text` property - you end up with invalid path. Change that to:

```
string filePath = txtUsername.Text.Trim() + ".txt";
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped, I knew it was just something simple that I had made a mistake on

Comment: @EmilyTomlinson don't forget to mark as answered, since it will confuse people otherwise and they will waste their time looking at already answered question.